# Design using Python and Functions

Tags: python, printing, function

I was shown this cool technique earlier this evening thanks to another member on stackoverflow.  I am a beginner at python, so most of my learning is done through reading this book I have and editing code to see how it would work.

I'm trying to design this for the bottom of the menu:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X  TASK1  X  TASK2  X  TASK3  X  TASK4  X  TASK5  X
X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

So you basically see this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X                                                 X
X          TASK MANAGER - TASK SELECTION          X
X                                                 X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X                                                 X
X                 READY TO START?                 X
X              ---------------------              X
X                PRESS THE 'ENTER'                X
X                  KEY TO BEGIN!                  X
X              ---------------------              X
X                                                 X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X  TASK1  X  TASK2  X  TASK3  X  TASK4  X  TASK5  X
X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The purpose of the bottom part would be that if you select say task 2, it would then just print a function for whichever is selected...so it would be (if task 2 selected):

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X                                                 X
X          TASK MANAGER - TASK SELECTION          X
X                                                 X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X                                                 X
X                 READY TO START?                 X
X              ---------------------              X
X                PRESS THE 'ENTER'                X
X                  KEY TO BEGIN!                  X
X              ---------------------              X
X                                                 X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X  TASK1  X  TASK2  X  TASK3  X  TASK4  X  TASK5  X
X   [ ]   X   [X]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Here is the current code:

```
def printLine (text = ''):
    print('X {: ^47} X'.format(text))

def printSelTitle (text = '', title = None):
    print('X{: ^9}'.format(text)),

def printSelCheck (text = '', title = None):
    print('X   [ ]   X'.format(text)),

def printBorder (title = None):
    print('X' * 51)

def printBox (*lines, title = None, showBottomBorder = False):
    printBorder(title)
    printLine()
    for line in lines:
        printLine(line)
    printLine()
    if showBottomBorder:
        printBorder()

printBox('TASK MANAGER - TASK SELECTION')
printBox('READY TO START?', '-' * 21, "PRESS THE 'ENTER'",\
         'KEY TO BEGIN!', '-' * 21, showBottomBorder = True)
printSelTitle('TASK1') and printSelTitle('TASK2')
printSelCheck()
printBorder()

printSelTitle('TASK3')
printSelTitle('TASK4')
printSelTitle('TASK5')
```

Here is what the current code looks like:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X                                                 X
X          TASK MANAGER - TASK SELECTION          X
X                                                 X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X                                                 X
X                 READY TO START?                 X
X              ---------------------              X
X                PRESS THE 'ENTER'                X
X                  KEY TO BEGIN!                  X
X              ---------------------              X
X                                                 X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X  TASK1  
X   [ ]   X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X  TASK3  
X  TASK4  
X  TASK5
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Best,

Steven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want no newline after `print`, don't use `print(aasd),` (this is tuple construction), but `print('123', end='')`

Printing syntax differences:
Python 2.x:

```
print "1", # special syntax for print statement
print "2"
```

Puthon 3:

```
print("1", end="") # actually returns None (print() is a function)
print("2")
```

Result in both cases:`12`

Python 3 (interactive shell):

```
>>> a = print('123')
123
>>> repr(a)
'None'
>>> a = print('123'),
123 # newline presents
>>> repr(a)
'(None,)' # result is tuple constructed by comma
```

Comment: Thanks.  That helped me figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code:

```
def printLine (text = ''):
    print('X {: ^47} X'.format(text))

def printSelTitle (text = '', title = None):
    print('X{: ^9}'.format(text), end = ""),

def printSelCheck (text = '', title = None):
    print('X   [ ]   '.format(text), end = "")

def printBorder (title = None):
    print('X' * 51)

def printBox (*lines, title = None, showBottomBorder = False):
    printBorder(title)
    printLine()
    for line in lines:
        printLine(line)
    printLine()
    if showBottomBorder:
        printBorder()

printBox('TASK MANAGER - TASK SELECTION')
printBox('READY TO START?', '-' * 21, "PRESS THE 'ENTER'",\
         'KEY TO BEGIN!', '-' * 21, showBottomBorder = True)
printSelTitle('TASK1'), printSelTitle('TASK2'),\
        printSelTitle('TASK3'), printSelTitle('TASK4'),\
        printSelTitle('TASK5'), print("X")
printSelCheck(), printSelCheck(), printSelCheck(),\
                 printSelCheck(), printSelCheck(), print("X")
printBorder()
```

Here is what it looks like:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X                                                 X
X          TASK MANAGER - TASK SELECTION          X
X                                                 X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X                                                 X
X                 READY TO START?                 X
X              ---------------------              X
X                PRESS THE 'ENTER'                X
X                  KEY TO BEGIN!                  X
X              ---------------------              X
X                                                 X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
X  TASK1  X  TASK2  X  TASK3  X  TASK4  X  TASK5  X
X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X   [ ]   X
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Still trying to layout how I would make the 'X' on select....but I'll look further into it.

Comment: def printSelCheck(text = '', title = None): \\
    print('X   [**{0}**]   '.format(text), end = "")

Comment: Thanks!  What do I read up on how to effect the result of {0}?

Comment: [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)